# How do I delete a database entry using Axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios, http-status-code-404, mern

I am attempting to delete reviews from my database using Axios and getting a 404 error. Create, Read and Update are all working correctly. I'm assuming it might be because my url in the delete request doesn't match the id listed in the database?

App.js Router:

```
          <Router>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Reviews}/>
            <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit}/>
            <Route path="/create" component={Create}/>
            <Route path="/delete/:id" component={Delete}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          </Router>
      </Container>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Delete Component:

```
export default class Delete extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
        title: '',
        releaseDate: 0,
        rating: 0,
        artist: '',
        review: ''
    }
}

  onSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
     axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/reviews/delete/'+this.props.match.params.id)
         .then(res => console.log(res.data));
     this.props.history.push('/')
 }

render() {
    return (
    <>
        <Jumbotron className='text-center'>
            <h2>Delete</h2>
        </Jumbotron>
        <div>   
            <h3>Delete "{this.state.title}" ?</h3>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete Review" className="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}
}
```

Server:

```
reviewRoutes.route('/delete/:id').post(function(req,res) {
    Review.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, review) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        const response = {
            message: "Review successfully deleted",
            id: review._id
        };
        return res.status(200).send(response);
    });
});
```

Error:
[image: 404 error]

[image: delete url]

Comment: It looks like your server route is setup as a post request not a delete request. 
reviewRoutes.route('/delete/:id').delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reviewRoutes.route('/delete/:id').delete(function(req,res) {
    Review.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, review) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        const response = {
            message: "Review successfully deleted",
            id: review._id
        };
        return res.status(200).send(response);
    });
});
```

You were making a post request instead of delete.

Comment: Thank you! idk how I missed this. Works fine now